# Django URLConf Redirect with odd characters

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm getting ready to move an old Classic ASP site to a new Django system. As part of the move we have to setup some of the old URLs to point to the new ones.

For example,
`http://www.domainname.com/category.asp?categoryid=105` should 301 to `http://www.domainname.com/some-category/`

Perhaps I'm regex stupid or something, but for this example, I've included in my URLconf this:
`(r'^asp/category\.asp\?categoryid=105$', redirect_to, {'url': '/some-category/'}),`

My thinking is that I have to escape the `.` and the `?` but for some reason when I go to test this, it does not redirect to `/some-category/`, it just 404s the URL as entered.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495263/28804), the query string is not part of the URL, so you'll probably want to write a view function that will grab the category from the query string and redirect appropriately.  You can have a URL like:

```
(r'^category\.asp', category_redirect),
```

And a view function like:

```
def category_redirect(request):
    if 'categoryid' not in request.GET:
        raise Http404
    cat_id = request.GET['category']
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(old_id=cat_id)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    else:
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/%s/' % cat.slug)
```

(Altered to your own tastes and needs, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `?` is not part of the URL. It's part of the GET parameters.